# How do I creat a colorful box containing a subtitle without being split by the command tcblower?

Tags: pdftex, tcolorbox

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to creat a colorful box that looks like the second picture?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because besides a screenshot there should also be code posted, which produced the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Next time, please add a [MWE (minimum working example)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) and describe what you have tried in more detail.

It was a bit unclear if you wanted to keep the split part before the subtitle or not.

I made a brief example that looks similar to what you want, but you might need to alter it to be exact.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{white!75!black}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=My title,
colback=yellow!15!white,
colframe=white!75!black,
colbacktitle=green!50!yellow!20!white!,
coltitle=red!25!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
subtitle style={boxrule=0pt,
colback=blue!40!green!20!white!,
colupper=black!75!gray} ]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}
\tcbsubtitle{My subtitle}
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

The output should look like this:
[image]